# Running subclasses through a battery of jasmine tests

Tags: unit-testing, coffeescript, angularjs, jasmine

So I'm building an angular project... And I have a class called "entries" with child classes like "twitter entries", "Facebook entries", etc.

Ideally I'd like to write one spec, and run all of the children classes through the specs. I haven't figured out how to do that.

Any suggestions on how to function-ize a jasmine spec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write a standard JS function that runs the Jasmine expectations, and pass each child class in via a separate spec. Something like:

```
describe("my multi-class spec suite", function(){
    //common specs for each child class
    var myExpectations = function(childClass) {
        expect(childClass).toBeDefined();
        expect(childClass.inheritedMethod()).toEqual("some common value");
        ...
    };

    //pass in your children classes
    it('should have twitter entries that behave', function(){
        myExpectations(new TwitterEntry());
    });

    it('should have facebook entries that behave', function(){
        myExpectations(new FacebookEntry());
    });
});
```

Comment: To be clear, I'm using CoffeeScript, and when I do this, I get an error: jasmine.Suite() required

Comment: Do you have any jasmine specs running successfully in your project? I've never seen that Jasmine.Suite() error; it appears to be thrown in line 1908 of Jasmine-1.1.0/jasmine.js

Comment: Yeah, it works totally normally. https://gist.github.com/4226335 When i try to add the fn, anywhere in the project, and then nest it into a different block, it dies.

Comment: Would you post a gist of the broken specs?

Comment: So it seems that if I don't nest it... it works just fine. The solution is to not nest the fn in a describe block. If the fn is scoped all the way outside, it works, anywhere inside the rest. (gist updated) This could also be a CoffeeScript thing.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's probably a CoffeeScript thing, which seems to create a lot of lambdas/closures behind the scenes for scoping fun. Anyway, hope this helps :-)